# How to get the ID from the html table row?

Tags: php, html

I already have a table that shows only one data, after clicking a button(edit) i need it to show/display the other data from the database through modal.
My problem is(for now), i cant fetch the ID for each row in the html table.
(once i can get the ID i think i can fetch the other datas)

Heres the PHP Code that show the table:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('ts_php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM job_posted";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table class='table'>
          <thead>
              <th>JOB</th>
              <th>STATUS</th>
              <th>APPLICATIONS</th>
              <th>EDIT</th>
              <th>DELETE</th>
          </thead>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr>
              <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
              <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
              <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
              <td><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>edit</a></td>
              <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
          </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Regarding the usage of the `mysql_*` functions in PHP, have a look at the answer to the question [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/7008354)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the primary key id of the job_posted table. Add id data attribute in your `a` tag and then access that id on the click of it.

```
<td><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>edit</a></td>
```

Replace `$row['id']` with you id key.

Comment: I've done it, but i still cant call it out, maybe because it was inside the while loop.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

For an example your primary_key is `id`. you need to change the `href` which is open modal to this

```
    <tr>
        <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
        <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
        <td><a data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-target='#myModal'>edit</a></td>
        <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
    </tr>";
```

and i think you need to change the way you open modal too. First adding class to your `href` for an example i will use `.openeditmodal`.

so your `href` will look like this

```
<a class='openeditmodal' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' data-target='#myModal'>edit</a>
```

then add this line to open modal.

```
  $(".openeditmodal").click(function(){
    var job_posted_id = $(this).data('id');
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: May i ask why i should i change the way i open my modal? what the difference? Thanks in advance

Comment: @sasugaAndrei Well, with that you can send `data-id` from your `href` .

Comment: yes and then inside the modal was the other data from that row. but i cant display the data maybe because the $row['id'] is inside the while loop. i dont have any problem with displaying my modal but thanks for that ill use that for future reference cheers

Comment: try to use `ajax` . so when the user click `edit`  the `ajax` will populate the data, then you can show the data to your modal

Comment: Okay, i just reviewed the link you've given to me, ill try to do it at home(sadly i need to go home now) Thank you very much for this, ill reply again if it works smoothly.

Comment: I tried the making this one, but the result of job_posted_id was undefined. sorry for the delayed response
EDIT: i change your code var job_posted_id = $(this).data('id'); into var job_posted_id = $(this).data('post_id');(which is my dataname. then i change it back into 'id' and it works!

Comment: glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

In inside your loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
echo "<tr>
          <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
          <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
          <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
          <td><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>edit</a></td>
          <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
      </tr>";
}
```

In your script

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e){
    var id= $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    console.log(id);

});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can get the id in hidden fields.

```
'<input type="hidden" value =' . $row["id"] . ' >'
```

you need to create primary key, auto increment in your database first column i.e your $row["id"]

```
<td><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>edit</a></td>
```

for your code check below.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr>
        <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th><td>" . $row['status'] . "</td><td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
                    <td><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
                    </tr>";
    }
```

Comment: Why input type? cant i use it on <a></a> tag?

Comment: it was just for example.

Comment: Ive done it but i still cant display the ID, maybe because its inside the while loop, any other way? i tried putting another variable but still doesnt work

Comment: can you show me the code and the primary key name in your table?
everyone use while loop your code seems fine. check the column name properly. id will also work in whole loop

Comment: i just updated your while loop with id part in my answer